# how to add a new word before specific word with sed regex

Tags: regex, sed

my origin file as below:

```
import a.b.c.io.AA
import a.b.c.util.io.anc;
```

I want to add *util* before specific word **io** which the word before it is not *util*.

this is my expected output file:

```
import a.b.c.io.AA
import a.b.c.util.io.anc;
```

I try this script:

```
find . -name "a.java"|xargs sed -ie 's/import.*[^u][^t][^i][^l].io.*/import.*.util.io*/' but dont get what I want.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate simple if-else conditional using `b` command

```
$ sed -e '/util\.io/b' -e 's/\.io/.util&/' ip.txt
import a.b.c.util.io.AA
import a.b.c.util.io.anc;
```

- `b` is branch instruction to jump to given label - if no label is given, it skips rest of sed script and starts next cycle
- `/util\.io/b` if the line contains `util.io`, start next cycle
- `s/\.io/.util&/` for rest of the lines, do this substitution

  - Use `/^import/ s/\.io/.util&/` to substitute only on lines starting with `import`

Also, you could use `-exec` with `find` instead of `xargs` - that is what the command was built for, to act upon files found

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i <...> {} +
```

Some versions might not support `{} +` in which case use `{} \;` instead. See also [Understanding the -exec option of find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/io/ && !/util\.io/{sub(/io/,".util.&");} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv  temp_file  Input_file` to above code too.